# Google doc generated by app script has unexpected owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

Beginner question – I have an app script in a Google Sheet (response sheet from a Google Form) generating Google Docs. It is unexpectedly making me the owner of those docs. The business owner is the owner of the form, sheet, doc template, and shared Google Drive folder where the docs are. She has given me edit access to all. She also is shown as the owner of the app script “project” in the sheet. The app script creates a copy of the template doc in the shared folder, and populates it with data from the form. I am the owner of these new documents, why is that? I am only editor of all the components involved. Can I fix it so that she is the default owner of the new docs?

Comment: I believe you are the Creator but the owner of the shared drive owns all of the files in the shared drive.

Comment: Look at the files in the share drive from Google Drive.  I have the exact same thing with another company.  The company owns all of the files but the different engineers that create different  projects are listed as the creators.

Comment: Thanks - my business owner is the creator and owner of the Google Drive. I had her create the shared folder and related components before I touched them. But it was a good suggestion. Problem solved ... it ended up being the trigger event that I created, as answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newly created documents will be owned by the account that runs the script. This is clear enough when you run the script manually, but it also happens when you run it through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). The trigger owner will own the files created while the function runs.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you and Laura below for pointing out this simple thing that I had overlooked. Much appreciated. I will delete the trigger and have the business owner create it.

Answer (score 1):

Check who owns the 'formSubmit' trigger.
(From your script editor, view your triggers. The left most column will show who the trigger is owned by.) Since your name is appearing as owner, the trigger is most likely still owned by you.

Comment: Thank you Laura and doubleunary for this simple solution. That's it!